# Make git merge result in a conflict when both versions have the same change

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Let's say in a git repo I have a file containing version information:

```
version=42
```

Now if on two separate branches the version is incremented to

```
version=43
```

and these branches are merged, the standard merge mechanism of git would not yield a merge conflict, since both versions are the same (even though the merge base is different).

Normally this is wanted behavior, but in the case of this file I want to get a merge conflict whenever both branches differ from the merge base. Is there any merge strategy that always ends in a merge conflict when a line is edited in both branches (even if they are the same)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  In fact, not only is there no such strategy built in to Git, the rest of Git's support routines—which you might want to use to *write* such a strategy—don't help you out here.  Existing merge drivers mostly use `git read-tree` (or its internal equivalent) to perform as much of the work as possible inside the index, and it's `git read-tree` itself that collapses such results back to a fully merged stage zero entry, saving having to re-code that same thing into the recursive and resolve merge drivers.

The culprit code is [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9a3764af74ac215e06543c263ec21196d672b49/unpack-trees.c#L1930-L1931).